# Fail at redirect expectation in a controller spec

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I am using Devise 1.4.2, RSpec 2.6.0 and Rails 3.1.0.rc6. My `routes.rb` looks like this:

```
scope "(:locale)", :locale => /e(s|n)/ do
  resources :demotivideos, :only => [:index, :show]
  devise_for :users

  namespace "admin" do
    resources :demotivideos, :except => [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

I am spec'ing that, when a not logged in user acces new, create or update, he should be redirected to `new_user_session_path`. For this, I am using the following code

```
context "when not logged in" do
  before(:each) do
    sign_out user
  end

  describe "GET new" do

    it "should redirect to new user session" do
      get :new
      response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
    end
  end

  describe "POST create" do

    it "should redirect to new user session" do
      post :create, :demotivideo => valid_attributes
      response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
    end
  end

  describe "PUT update" do

    it "should redirect to new user session" do
      put :update, :id => 1, :demotivideo => valid_attributes
      response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
    end
  end
end
```

All are failing because of the same reason: expected route includes the locale (by default en) but the actual redirect was to the same path without locale. My application controller was modified as told in [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery

  before_filter :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options={})
    logger.debug "default_url_options is passed options: #{options.inspect}\n"
    { :locale => I18n.locale }
  end

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like though [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-the-url-params) uses `def default_url_options` in [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a--Redirect-with-locale-after-authentication-failure) you need `def self.default_url_options`. Don't know the difference, though.